# Looking NULL values for different Oracle Type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, null, nvl

I'm doing collection of two columns(col & val). Into second select col is parameter of other columns and val is value of this column.

[image]

```
declare
  TYPE t_my_list is record(id varchar2(1000), col VARCHAR2(4000),val VARCHAR2(4000));
  TYPE list_3STR is table of t_my_list;    
  v_stmt    VARCHAR2(32000) := 'SELECT id, col, val FROM userA.tableA';
  v_lstmt   VARCHAR2(32000);
  v_ret     list_3STR := list_3STR();
  cDel   number;

begin
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret;

  for i in v_ret.first..v_ret.last loop
   v_lstmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM userB.tableB 
      WHERE NVL('||v_ret (i).col||', ''<null>'') in ('''||v_ret (i).val||''', ''<null>'') and idB = '''||v_ret (i).id||'''';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_lstmt INTO cDel;
    If cDel > 0 Then
    --some code
    cDel = 0;   
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

But into my select statement I can have null so I'm using NVL. Also, as I can have number so I need to use convert `to_char('||v_ret (i).col||')`. Also, type of column is number, RAW, date etc..

**My question:**

- is other posibility then NVL?
- if not, has oracle default converter? (all types need to be Varchar2)

Comment: [Please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). And include the result you currently see, and what you want to see if they are different. Is your null handling supposed to be saying that the target column can be null or match the target `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to do:

```
   v_lstmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM userB.tableB WHERE id = '''||v_ret (i).id||''''
     || ' and ('||v_ret (i).col||' is null or '||v_ret (i).col||' = :val)';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_lstmt INTO cDel using v_ret (i).val;
```

That checks that the column is null *or* matches the supplied `val`, and uses a bind variable to supply the value to check to cut down parsing a bit.

However this still relies on implicit conversion, so if you had a date value in the table for instance you'd be relying on your NLS settings to convert it to match the target table column type.

You can use the `all_tab_columns` view to find the data type of the target column and do explicit conversion of the `val` to that type before binding. A more involved but possibly more robust approach would be to use `dbms_sql` for the inner dynamic SQL instead of `execute immediate`.

The outer query doesn't seem to need to be dynamic though, you coudl do:

```
declare
  v_lstmt   VARCHAR2(32000);
  cDel   number;
begin
  for rec in (SELECT id, col, val FROM tableA) loop
    v_lstmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM tableB WHERE id = '''||rec.id||''''
      || ' and ('||rec.col||' is null or '||rec.col||' = :val)';


    dbms_output.put_line(v_lstmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_lstmt INTO cDel using rec.val;
    If cDel > 0 Then
      --some code
      cDel := 0;   
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: thnak you, that's ok, but what if I got null for both site? ** v_ret (i).val** so I need to compare null to null...how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? If `tablea.val` is null? If so what should that match in `tableb`? It will match anyway at the moment if the target column is null, from `rec.col is null`?

Comment: tableA - for id10, colAAAA, val is null.....now equal this null with tableB - id10, AAAA = null....how to compare it? Result for me need to be 1

Comment: The query in the answer evaluates to `and (AAAA is null or AAAA = :val)` so that will match. (Nothing is equal to or not equal to null, so you have to use `is null`).

Comment: `:val` is a bind variable placeholder, it shouldn't be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to include situations when v_ret (i).col is NULL.

If so, you can try using the following code in your select statement:

```
WHERE ('||v_ret (i).col||' is null OR '||v_ret (i).col||' = '||v_ret (i).val||')
```

instead of:

```
WHERE NVL('||v_ret (i).col||', ''<null>'') in ('''||v_ret (i).val||''', ''<null>'')
```

As a default converter you may try using **CAST** function: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html

Comment: Might be more useful to link to [the Oracle RDBMS docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html) *8-) You still need to know which data type to cast to though.

Comment: @AlexPoole hahah true that! :D