# Column Transpositions into Oracle (pl/sql, sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, null, transpose

I'm doing transpositions and looking if for some column exist exactly the same value into other table. Example:

```
tableA: id = 10, col = abc , value = 10

tableB: id = 10, abc = 10
```

I have below code:

```
declare
  TYPE  t_my_list is record(id VARCHAR2(4000),col VARCHAR2(4000),val VARCHAR2(4000));
  Type list_3STR is table of t_my_list;

  v_stmt VARCHAR2(32000) := 'SELECT id, col, val FROM userA.tableA';
  v_lstmt VARCHAR2(32000);
  v_ret list_3STR := list_3STR();      
  cDel   number; 
begin
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret;  

    for i in v_ret.first..v_ret.last loop
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: '||v_ret (i).id||', COL: '||v_ret (i).col||', VAL: '||v_ret (i).val);

        v_lstmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM userB.tableB WHERE NVL(cast('||v_ret (i).col||' as Varchar2(100)), ''<null>'') in ('''||v_ret (i).val||''', ''<null>'') and ID = '''||v_ret (i).id||''' ';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_lstmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_lstmt INTO cDel;

         If cDel > 0 Then
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('delete row from userA.tableA')
         End if;

    end loop;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ret = '||v_ret.count);   
end;
```

I have to consider **5 CASE**:

userA.tableA to userB.tableB

1. NULL to NULL = 1 --DELETE value
2. NULL to DATA = 0 --NOT DELETE
3. the same DATA to DATA = 1 --DELETE
4. diffrent DATA to diffrent DATA = 0 --NOT DELETE
5. DATA to NULL = 0 = --NOT DELETE

My code is working for case 1 to 4. How to resolve 5th problem?

Update: CASE example:

```
1. 
id = 10, col = test, val = null
id = 10, test = null

2.
id = 10, col = test, val = null
id = 10, test = 99

3.
id = 10, col = test, val = 99
id = 10, test = 99

4.
id = 10, col = test, val = 5
id = 10, test = 99

5.
id = 10, col = test, val = 4
id = 10, test = null
```

Comment: Is there a reason for dynamic SQL? Are there some restrictions, preventing to write one delete statement and specify the logic in "where" part?

Comment: yes, I need to use dynamic SQL and I'm not able to use cursor

Comment: Why can't you use a cursor? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Also, please provide sample input data that matches each scenario and provide the output you're expecting.

Comment: @Boneist - we can't as is this standard inside company

Comment: Dummy data is also good. Any data is good. Data is good. Help us to help you.

Comment: I have just put dummy data

Comment: @4est you can't use cursors because that's a standard in your company? WTF? That's like saying you can only do your job by typing with your nose. \*frowns\* If it's for performance reasons, since 10g cursor for loops have been optimised to do `bulk collect ... limit 100` behind the scenes. Also, doing a bulk collect without using the limit clause - as you're doing in your sample code - can use up a lot of memory; I imagine that should be part of your standards not to bulk collect without the limit clause?

Comment: if I use cursor and someone delete tableA or tableB then I need to re-compile packages etc....if I'm correct with dynamic sql I don't need to do it

Comment: @4est - you mean drop, rather than delete? Tables shouldn't generally be created or dropped on the fly. But if they are dropped you'll get a run-time error from your package; and if they are dropped and recreated the package will be automatically recompiled next time it's called. (Also, you can use dynamic SQL with a cursor without using bulk collect...)

Comment: Also in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51667533/266304) I showed using `is null` instead of `nvl()`, which would work for scenarios 2 and 5. Why have you done back to `nvl()` and magic values?

Comment: I have discoution with project lead and he asked me to use dynamic sql, that why I'm looking diffrent way.....also "drop table" - not here in the procedure, but some user in the future can just do it

Comment: What is the ultimate aim of this procedure? To delete rows from table A where there's a matching row in table B?

Comment: @Boneist you have right, as I need to validate the data after insert, updates etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this (if I absolutely had to do it this way) is to find out what columns need to be compared to in table b, then you can work out what the values in table a can be used to compare with those columns.

Once you have that (by querying user_tables (or all_tables/dba_tables as necessary) to retrieve the relevant columns), you can then generate a join clause.

The join clause needs to check that either both columns are null or both columns have the same non-null value.

Once you have that, you can then use that in a merge statement to delete the rows that match the join condition. We do that by first updating the matched rows (which we need to do in order for those rows to be seen by the delete in the next step) and then delete them.

Here's a working test case:

**Setup:**

```
create table a (id integer, col varchar2(30), val number, constraint a_pk primary key (id, col));

create table b (id integer, abc number, test number, xyz number, constraint b_pk primary key (id));

insert into a (id, col, val)
select 10, 'test', null from dual union all
select 11, 'test', null from dual union all
select 12, 'test', 99 from dual union all
select 13, 'test', 5 from dual union all
select 14, 'test', 4 from dual union all
select 10, 'abc', 1 from dual union all
select 10, 'xyz', 7 from dual union all
select 11, 'abc', 4 from dual union all
select 11, 'xyz', 6 from dual union all
select 12, 'abc', 12 from dual union all
select 12, 'efg', 30 from dual union all
select 13, 'abc', 3 from dual union all
select 13, 'xyz', 5 from dual union all
select 14, 'abc', 8 from dual union all
select 14, 'xyz', 9 from dual;

insert into b (id, abc, test, xyz)
select 10, 1, null, 7 from dual union all
select 11, 4, 99, 8 from dual union all
select 12, 11, 99, 30 from dual union all
select 13, 1, 5, 5 from dual union all
select 14, 1, null, 7 from dual;

commit;
```

**Rows we're expecting to remain in table a**

```
select a.*
from   a tgt
        full outer join b src on (tgt.id = src.id
      and (1 = 0
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'ABC' and (tgt.val = src.ABC or (tgt.val is null and src.ABC is null)))
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'TEST' and (tgt.val = src.TEST or (tgt.val is null and src.TEST is null)))
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'XYZ' and (tgt.val = src.XYZ or (tgt.val is null and src.XYZ is null)))))
where tgt.id is not null and src.id is NULL
ORDER BY a.id, a.col;

ID COL  VAL
-- ---- ---
11 test    
11 xyz    6
12 abc   12
12 efg   30
13 abc    3
14 abc    8
14 test   4
14 xyz    9
```

**Run the code**

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  v_sql clob;
begin
  v_sql := 'merge into a tgt' || chr(10) ||
           '  using  b src' || chr(10) ||
           '  on (tgt.id = src.id' || chr(10) ||
           '      and (1 = 0';

  -- Generate the join conditions
  for rec in (select '           or (upper(tgt.col) = '''||column_name||''' and (tgt.val = src.'||column_name||' or (tgt.val is null and src.'||column_name||' is null)))' join_condition
              from   user_tab_columns
              where  table_name = 'B'
              and    column_name != 'ID')
  loop
    v_sql := v_sql || chr(10) || rec.join_condition;
  end loop;

  v_sql := v_sql || '))' || chr(10) ||
                    'when matched then' || chr(10) || -- we only care about rows that match on the join clause
                    '  update set tgt.col = tgt.col' || chr(10) || -- we need to physically update those rows, or the delete clause won't see them.
                    '  delete where 1=1'; -- we need to have the where clause here, but we're deleting all rows that were updated in the previous step, hence 1=1 which is always true.

  dbms_output.put_line (v_sql||';');

  execute immediate v_sql;
end;
/
```

**dbms_output of the statement**

```
merge into a tgt
  using  b src
  on (tgt.id = src.id
      and (1 = 0
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'ABC' and (tgt.val = src.ABC or (tgt.val is null and src.ABC is null)))
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'TEST' and (tgt.val = src.TEST or (tgt.val is null and src.TEST is null)))
           or (upper(tgt.col) = 'XYZ' and (tgt.val = src.XYZ or (tgt.val is null and src.XYZ is null)))))
when matched then
  update set tgt.col = tgt.col
  delete where 1=1;
```

**Check we have the columns we expected would remain**

```
select *
from   a
order by id, col;

ID COL  VAL
-- ---- ---
11 test    
11 xyz    6
12 abc   12
12 efg   30
13 abc    3
14 abc    8
14 test   4
14 xyz    9
```

**However, if you have any choice over the matter, I would seriously, seriously ask you to rethink this design.**

Having key-values in table a is a very strange way to go about updating table b with, and as you have found out, it makes doing the simplest things very tricky.

Comment: thank you @Boneist for great explanation and examples

Comment: Just to add, I suggest doing it in a single merge statement so that you only query table b once, rather than for each row in table a. You should amend the query on user_tab_columns to pick out only those columns that are relevant for the checks. You may also need to amend the query to do different things for different column datatypes, e.g. you may need to throw a to_date around the a.val column with the appropriate format mask, in order to properly compare the value to the table b column.